# I am not able to host my own Web site

Tags: web-hosting, portforwarding

I have a high speed cable internet connection at home. I have D-link router, and I connect 2 computers, one is a desktop running Windows XP, the other is a laptop running Windows 7. I am perfectly able to use internet on both computers.

Now I want to host my personal web site from my home computer. I have already built the site that is running on my home network. Now I want to make it accessible from internet. I did all the procedures to open the appropriate ports on my router, allow incoming connections, and port forwarding setup, using the router's guide : http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DIR/DIR%20826L/Manual/DIR_826L_MANUAL_EN_UK.pdf .

However I am still not able to see my web site from public internet. 
When I try to go to my site using my local IP address (192.168.0.103) or computer name, the site is loaded on other home computer, but when I try the same using my public IP address (found with "what is my ip" on google search), I get "Page cannot be loaded" error.

Can someone please help me telling what I am doing wrong, and how the problem can be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to hit your WAN IPaddress from inside your house, aka, on the lan that the WAN would hit?  It could be NAT Reflection/lack thereof getting in your way.  Make sure you're trying to hit your WAN IP from a network outside of your local network.  If you have a phone, turn off wifi, and use your phone.

Besides that, you've listed all of the basic steps necessary.  Should the above not be the problem, I would start by checking your PCs firewall.  In particular on Windows 7 checking to make sure you click real hard on that "public networks" button.  Then just try and ping port 80, not load the webpage.  If you can't ping, it suggests configuration issues with your router/connection.  If you can, there's just some configuration that's effed up with your webserver.

Comment: I am able to ping to my public IP from home computer. Next time, after doing port forwarding, I will try to access my site from public internet using a device outside of my Wifi (my cell phone). Thanks.